# Multiple Fonts in Same Family

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

I was wondering if it was possible to add multiple styles of the same font to the @font-face tag.  I read a few places where it said it was possible, but every time I've tried it's just used the default font.  My current example with the fictional Coolio font includes:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Coolio;
    src: url("../fonts/coolio.otf)";
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Coolio;
    src: url("../fonts/coolio-bold.otf)";
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Coolio;
    src: url("../fonts/coolio-italic.otf)";
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Coolio;
    src: url("../fonts/coolio-bolditalic.otf)";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Coolio;
    src: url("../fonts/coolio-condensed.otf)";
    font-stretch: condensed;
}
```

...and so on and so forth.  (I'm actually using numerical weights rather than just bold or normal, but it doesn't work either way.)

So is it possible or were the articles I read just incorrect?  I'm thinking I'd have to define each one with its own name, but that kind of defeats the point of just using one family and then relying on the various CSS tags to hand the styling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything like this.  When you use the fonts, you should be able to set bold, etc on the css selectors.

Comment: To explain further, some fonts have specific variants that are different from the base font.  For example, if you use "bold," it would use an actual bold version of the font, rather than just thickening up the base font.

I'm well aware that I could just use normal weights and styles with a base font.  That's not what I'm trying to do here, though. :)

Comment: What you are doing is exactly right and should work, so if it's not, the problem lies elsewhere. What do you mean by "default font"--do you mean it falling back to generic `sans-serif` or something, or it is using `../fonts/coolio/otf` and applying its own bolding to it, or...? Test it by using a different font-family for one of the variants, like "CoolioItalic", and make sure that works, or doesn't; that will validate that the relative path is correct and the font is getting loaded correctly, for example.

Comment: Yes, it keeps defaulting to the coolio.otf font no matter what I try to do, as shown above.  And yes, I've tested to make sure the file paths are correct (I switched the coolio.otf in the first tag to coolio-extrabold.otf and it showed up, but when I switched it back it continued using coolio.otf whenever I used "bold").

Comment: @brian this is actually exactly what you should do. Multiple declarations for the same font family, with different source files for different weights and styles. Fonts don't come with "bold" and "italic" built in, those are separate font files, (When MS Word or Photoshop etc let you pick "bold" or "italic", they're actually switching font files)

Comment: @Funkenstein why is this a fictional example? Your CSS is just fine, why didn't you just try this and discovered that it worked exactly as you intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct syntax, and works fine, as can be seen in the following runnable snippet:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Coolio;
  src: url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v7/10JVD_humAd5zP2yrFqw6nhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Coolio;
  src: url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/greatvibes/v4/6q1c0ofG6NKsEhAc2eh-3YbN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff) format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  font-family: Coolio;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Font family demonstrator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is some text</h1>
    <p>And this is also text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

For illustrative purposes, those are two *completely different* fonts, but we told the CSS that they're both in the "Coolio" family, with font-weight acting as differentiator.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  I don't see an option along those lines. :(